# What are the default Startup Applications Preferences in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, startup-applications

What are the default **Startup Applications Preferences** entries of a clean Ubuntu 16.04 installation?

**Example of my modified preferences that I would like to clean-up:**

[image: Startup Applications Preferences]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entries in `~/.config/autostart` are the ones that you have added *in addition* to the default ones. By comparing the entries there with what you see in the Startup Applications Preferences GUI, you can tell that the default startup applications are:

- GNOME Software (No description)
- Indicator Application (No description)
- SSH Key Agent (GNOME Keyring: SSH Agent)

If you want to restore the default startup applications, from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387844&p=8713404#post8713404, you can simply do:

```
rm -r ~/.config/autostart
```

If you don't want to delete the directory for good, you can consider renaming it to something you prefer (say, `autostart.bak`):

```
mv ~/.config/autostart ~/.config/autostart.bak
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very surprised to see that only 3 entries are the default ones. Not even `Blueman Applet` is part of default?

Comment: @orschiro Yeah there are only 3 default entries on my Ubuntu 16.04 (with Unity) machine. I don't have the blueman applet; that seems to be provided by the `blueman` package which I don't have installed.

Comment: Hi Ed, could you add the command for Gnome software, please? (yup, deleted that one instead of another one)